# Series about a ranger with a staff that turns into a bow

Tags: story-identification, novel

So here's a gooder. I completely forget the name of or how many books there are in the series. There's a human ranger raised by elves. One of his tasks as a young boy was to collect water using the spongey rocks. He is trained in using a bow staff that turns into a bow. Then during a trial where he fights a skeleton he gets given or finds a sword, because his bow is useless.

There's a bunch of monks that are trained in hand to hand combat, that also gain powers from magic stones. Like the ability to cast fireballs or become half tiger ect... the stones are collected once every 25 or 50 years when they rain from the heavens onto the isle of pimminicut. One of the monks leaves the monestary or whatever he happens to be a part of. He often when fighting will yell "HO HO WHAT".

Can anyone help me find these books?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the *[Demonwar Saga](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_DemonWars_Saga)* (1997-2003) by R.A. Salvatore:

> The first book in the trilogy introduces the reader to Elbryan Wyndon and Jilseponie Ault, two young friends whose lives are irrevocably changed by the destruction of their village of Dundalis, and Avelyn Desbris, a pious young man who enters the monastery of St.-Mere-Abelle in order to study and to serve God. Divided by the catastrophe, Elbryan and Pony (Jilseponie's nickname) struggle to sort out their lives. Elbryan is taken in by the Touel'alfar, the winged elves of Corona. Jilseponie makes her way to the city of Palmaris where she is raised by the Chilichunks, a husband and wife who own a tavern in the city. Meanwhile, Avelyn comes to terms with the all-too-human brothers of the Abellican Church and the myriad injustices he witnesses them cause.
>
> Years pass before the trio meet. During their time apart Elbryan is trained by the Touel'alfar as a ranger and takes on the name Nightbird. Meanwhile, Pony becomes a barmaid at the Chilichunk's tavern, Fellowship Way and eventually enters into the military after marrying the nobleman Conner Bildeborough and then rejecting him on their wedding night; the marriage is immediately annulled. Avelyn, a promising young monk at St. Mere-Abelle begins learning the use of the powerful gemstone magic, but eventually leaves the Church after finding it to not be the holy place he had hoped for and receiving a vision of the awakened demon dactyl. It will be up to these three, along with a group of friends and allies, to save the world from the demon dactyl, Bestesbulzibar, and his dark force of goblins, powries and fomorian giants.

---

Found with a Google Books search for *["ho ho what” magic stones](https://books.google.com/books?id=m_tZAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT519&dq=%22ho+ho+what%22+magic+stones&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjPtrG1i7XhAhUEOK0KHSvgCIEQuwUIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22ho%20ho%20what%22%20&f=false)*.

Comment: If this is the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: Thank you. I've been wondering for quite some time what the books were called. I shall definitely be picking them up soon. Once again thank you so much.